# Is there a way to pass predefined macros from project that used as reference for another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

I have the following projects:

- Application.vcxproj (ref to CoreStaticLib)
- CoreStaticLib.vcxproj (ref to HelpersLib)
- HelpersLib.vcxproj

How can i pass predefined macros from HelpersLib to CoreStaticLib when i include some header from HelpersLib in CoreStaticLib or Application the macros will be available in this projects? For example some macro is *ENABLE_LOG* and it must be avaliable in Application.

Manually import HelpersLib.targets in each project doesn't suitable for me.

Comment: I assume you mean a preprocessor macro. You can define the macro in the HelpersLib header file and it will be available where the header file is included.

Comment: @isrepeat Hi, you could take a look at the answer I posted. If you were talking about other things, please feel free to correct me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define macros in .h file or .cpp file, then after the include step, you will be able to use them(In general, we don't use the .cpp to define.).

For example, this is the structure of the cpp solution on my side:

[image]

This is the content of the header file HelpersLib.h on my side:

```
#pragma once

#define ENABLE_LOG true
```

And then you could refer the header file which contains the macros you want.

Both in .h and .cpp you could include macros like this way:

`#include "<The path of the header file which contains macros.>"`

For example, on my side it is:

`#include "..\HelpersLib\HelpersLib.h"`

After that, you will be able to use it in other projects:

[image]

You can put the reference step in the header file in current project. Then just use the header file of current project in cpp file. Or you can directly include the original .h file in current file for each time you want to use the macros.

**Please pay attention to the path of the .h file, make sure it is correct. otherwise you will be unable to use the macros.**

If you want to ask if there is a simple way to make the macros in the referenced project available anywhere in the current project in one step, then I think there is no such method. This thing is ultimately file based rather than an overall project setup. If the question is talking about something else, please let me know.

Comment: Hello. This option doesn't suit me. I have a written SomeNuget that I connected to HelpersLib.vcxproj. And since with nuget the SomeNuget.targets also connected automatically i have access to predefined macros of SomeNuget.

Comment: So HelpersLib can work with nuget. And depending on whether SomeNuget is connected to it, I can turn on/off some parts of the code through macros. There are no problems with .cpp, because they are used only for compiling HelpersLib, but for headers this will only work inside HelpersLib, but not outside because we can't pass a predefined macros from SomeNuget to HelpersLib and from it to CoreStaticLib and from it to Application.